# _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int?' in type cast) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My app Can't start due to this error in Flutter:

[image: Error]

```
final Map<String, Object> _preferenceCache;

  /// Returns all keys in the persistent storage.
  Set<String> getKeys() => Set<String>.from(_preferenceCache.keys);

  /// Reads a value of any type from persistent storage.
  Object? get(String key) => _preferenceCache[key];

  /// Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's not a
  /// bool.
  bool? getBool(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as bool?;

  /// Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's not
  /// an int.
  int? getInt(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as int?;

  /// Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's not a
  /// double.
  double? getDouble(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as double?;

  /// Reads a value from persistent storage, throwing an exception if it's not a
  /// String.
  String? getString(String key) => _preferenceCache[key] as String?;
```

I tried to add `.toString()` but still don't work.

Comment: Can you share the code where `getInt` is used?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`_preferenceCache[key]` giving you `String`. Instead of using `as` it would be better to use `tryParse`, you can convert to int like

```dart
 int? getInt(String key) => int.tryParse("${_preferenceCache[key]}");
```

More about [tryParse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/tryParse.html)